# Discord.js bot reply with slash command

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, discord, discord.js

I have a working slash command, which is great. I can use the command with one input parameter eg `/command string` and it will execute the command.
However I am looking to set up a Discord bot that uses that command in a channel every 5 or so minutes. I can't seem to get the bot to use the command, any ideas on how to get it to work?

It just displays the string in the channel but the bot doesn't execute the command.

```
bot.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {
    if (msg.content === "!loop") {
        interval = setInterval (function () {
            msg.channel.send("/command string")
        }, 3 * 1000);
    }
})
```

Comment: All normal bots ignore messages/commands from other bots so you can't abuse your own bot

Comment: Dammit... I want to abuse my own bot lol. Hmm will have to think of a work around

Comment: I don't think bots can see nor run slash commands, whether your own or any other bots'. Your code doesn't work because `channel.send` can only send text, starting with a slash doesn't turn it into a slash command call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bots can only receive [Application Command Interactions](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands), not create them. This means your bot won't be able to run other bot's slash commands, click their buttons or use their dropdown menus.

If you have control over the other bot's code, though, you can set it up to listen for **messages** (not interactions) from your second bot, and run code accordingly.

But be aware: as MegaMix mentioned in their comment, if the bot you want to control isn't yours, you probably won't be able to do that, as **[it is a best practice](https://github.com/meew0/discord-bot-best-practices) to ignore messages from other bots** to prevent abuse and infinite loops.